# Dates cannot be converted to long

Tags: java, oracle, date

I have been trying to insert date using the jdatepicker. Right now I am using this code

```
           ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(startdate.getDate().getTime()));
```

but is giving me date:time. If I try to remove the .getTime, i will get the following error "Dates cannot be converted to long"

```
           ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(startdate.getDate()));
```

What should I do to just insert the date only? By the format yyyy-MM-dd. Thank you.

Comment: Oracle does not have a "date only" data type. A `DATE` column ***always*** contains a time. There is nothing you can do about

Comment: So there is not way I can insert the date only?

Comment: As I said: Oracle does not have a "date only" data type. The usual workaround for this is to always "normalize" the date to use `00:00:00` as the time. _Theoretically_ the JDBC driver should do that when using `setDate()` with a `java.sql.Date` and the 11.x drivers have been doing that (at least after a configuration option). But the 12.x driver blatantly ignores the JDBC specs and **always** returns and stores a proper time value. Although it's a violation of the JDBC specs, Oracle refuses to fix this - they call it a feature.

Comment: Yea right now it keeps grabbing my current time whenever I do an insert.

Comment: One hack would be to use something like `insert into foo (date_column, ...) values (trunc(?), ?, ?)` which would set the time to `00:00:00`

Comment: Yeah it works! back to 00:00:00. Thanks heaps!